# Install reportportal on kube get error : starting Tomcat context. Exception: org...message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar'

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, rabbitmq, reportportal

I've installed reportportal 5.7.0 to kubernetes cluster. I've implemented it from doc:https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/tree/develop/reportportal. From the doc,I have to install rabbitmq, postgres and minio for reportportal. I've successfully installed abbitmq, postgres and minio. All pods were running but when I've installed reportportal. Report-portal-api pods was error. I've get logs form the pods then the pods logs shown that

> o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat
> context. Exception: org.springframework
> .beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean
> with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/bo
> ot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantia tion via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actu
> ate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method
> 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.B eanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'infoEndpoint' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/info/InfoEnd
> pointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed  to
> instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.InfoEndpoint]:
> Factory method 'infoEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.be ans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'infoContributorComposite' defined in
> URL [jar:file:/service-api-5.7.0-exec.jar!/BOO
> T-INF/classes!/com/epam/ta/reportportal/info/InfoContributorComposite.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested excepti on is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'analyzerInfoContributor' defined in URL
> [jar:file:/serv
> ice-api-5.7.0-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/epam/ta/reportportal/info/AnalyzerInfoContributor.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor p arameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'managementTemplate' defined in class p ath
> resource
> [com/epam/ta/reportportal/core/configs/rabbit/AnalyzerRabbitMqConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exceptio n is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.analyzer.auto.client.RabbitMqManagementClient]
> : Factory method 'managementTemplate' threw exception; nested
> exception is com.epam.ta.reportportal.exception.ReportPortalException:
> Unclassified Report Porta l Error

I suspected that reportportal connect to rabbitmq was error but I'm not sure. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That's true. Double-check your rabbitmq configuration: connection URL, open ports, etc. We have a step-by-step guide on Kubernetes deployment: https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/tree/develop/reportportal

Comment: Thank you for answer myquestion. I have check rabbitmq pod. I access rabbitmq amqp 
by use kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/rabbitmq 5672:5672
then I can add queue and get queue by use rabbitmqadmin. I thought the 
rabbitmq pod was running. for values.yaml, I have config like this
rabbitmq:
  SecretName: ""
  installdep:
    enable: false
  endpoint:
    address: rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local
    port: 5672
    user: rabbitmq
    apiport: 15672
    apiuser: rabbitmq
    password: <my password>

Comment: I'm not sure about my config and I wonder that Should I use kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/rabbitmq 5672:5672
while reportportal connect to rabbitmq? (I never use kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/rabbitmq 5672:5672 while reportportal connect to rabbitmq )